# How to avoid useEffect to trigger another useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

i have a problem with my useEffect and my code.

We will focus on this state :

```
const [acceptedAppeals, setAcceptedAppeals] = useState([]);
```

Here the first useEffect that is trigger each timeid of currentAppeal changed. You can notice it changes "AccepetedAppeal" to [] because i want to initialize my array each time the id change.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setAcceptedAppeals([]);
  }, [currentAppeal.id]);
```

I have a second use Effect that is trigger every time i change AcceptedAppeals too:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (questions) {
      if (questions.length != acceptedAppeals.length && acceptedAppeals.length > 0) {
        setCurrentAppeal({ ...currentAppeal, status: closePartial });
      } else if (acceptedAppeals.length <= 0) {
        setCurrentAppeal({ ...currentAppeal, status: closeUnsuccefull });
      } else {
        setCurrentAppeal({ ...currentAppeal, status: closeSuccefull });
      }
    }
  }, [acceptedAppeals]);
```

The problem is when the first useEffect is called, it calls the second useEffect. But i don't want it. There is a way to do it ?

I'm calling the second useEffect via this function :

```
  const handleQuestionAccepted = (event, question) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      setAcceptedAppeals([...acceptedAppeals, question]);
    } else {
      setAcceptedAppeals(acceptedAppeals.filter((item) => item !== question));
    }
  };
```

I also tried to moved all the stuff on the second useEffect inside this function.But the new problem will be that the state don't have time to update before calling the second setstate. For example here if i do :

```
  const handleQuestionAccepted = (event, question) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      setAcceptedAppeals([...acceptedAppeals, question]);
    } else {
      setAcceptedAppeals(acceptedAppeals.filter((item) => item !== question));
    }
    if (questions) {
      if (questions.length != acceptedAppeals.length && acceptedAppeals.length > 0) {
        setCurrentAppeal({ ...currentAppeal, status: closePartial });
      } else if (acceptedAppeals.length <= 0) {
        setCurrentAppeal({ ...currentAppeal, status: closeUnsuccefull });
      } else {
        setCurrentAppeal({ ...currentAppeal, status: closeSuccefull });
      }
    }
  };
```

The problem will be  `acceptedAppeals` will not be updated because setAcceptedAppeals will be triggered in same time or not fast enough to use it just after

Thank for your help

Comment: I am not sure you understand how `useEffect` works . Why have two `useEffect` hooks? Just handle both cases in the same hook with if statements and leave the more inclusive state as the trigger ...

Answer (score 0):

In fact you want to have a `useEffect` that ignores certain changes of its dependencies? Certainly not possible. Check in your second `useEffect` if `acceptedAppeals.length == 0`.

Or you could also find a clever way to empty the array without changing its reference - which won't trigger the second `useEffect` - for example by doing `acceptedAppeals.length = 0` but I definitely do not recommend it, it is not good practice.